# I need to make api in geotab server using .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

How to call .net core web api to geotab server?

How to call .net core Web API to create api to connect with geotab server? I tried and spent more time but not found any solution  ...

Comment: Could you please share how did you try that and if you encounter any problems or error? You have to install `nuget` package for [`Geotab.Checkmate`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geotab.Checkmate.ObjectModel/). Here is a [`complete example`](https://geotab.github.io/sdk/software/guides/using-in-dotnet/#example-code) of how you could implement that.

Comment: I am creating api for sending gps data to geotab but got some error

Comment: Please Share the `code snippet` and what `error` you are getting and include that in detail within the question.

Comment: {
    "method": "AddData",
    "params": {
        "apiKey": "0fff5b0b-ab74-4eb2-ba78-8b87f4ceaa45",
        "sessionId": "f04b342d-5380-4b49-914f-acc6b60c2f77",
        "recordsToAdd": [
            {
                "serialNo": "CX8D2181A250",
                "dateTime": "2016-11-23T20:28:40.648Z",
                "isIgnitionOn": true,
                "isGpsValid": true,
                "latitude": 43.7550583,
                "longitude": -79.4769897,
                "speed": 52.0,
                "type": "ThirdPartyGpsRecord"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Above request below response.    {"error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"Access Violation - User not authorized for THIRD-PARTY-INTEGRATOR role (Ref ID: 0HMJ1LC9AVJTA:00000002)","errors":[{"name":"SecurityException","message":"SecurityException: Access Violation - User not authorized for THIRD-PARTY-INTEGRATOR role"}]}}

Comment: The error message clearly stated that your credential is not valid as it says `unauthorized`. Make sure your credentials are correct at this point `var api = new API(userName, password, null, databaseName, server);`

Comment: after Admin Login I am using apiKey and sessionID.

Comment: So but `geotab document` says this format. could please try according to their given fomrat if that works.

Comment: I make the API for sending gpsData to mygeotab database . I read many documents and try to send gpsData to mygeotab database. But I have no solution so anyone know about this than tell me example for this question.